# Configuring mutt for S/MIME on OS X

Tags: macos, mutt

I exported my CA chain (Deutsche Telekom > DFN > Uni Koeln) using

```
smime_keys add_root CertName.cer
```

after exporting the relevant certificates from my keychain. But when I import my personal certificate issued by Uni Koeln using

```
smime_keys add_p12 MyCertName.p12
```

the following error occurs

```
Couldn't identify root certificate!
No root and no intermediate certificates. Can't continue. at /usr/local/bin/smime_keys line 669.
```

although the imported root certificates are present in ~/.smime/ca-bundle.crt and .muttrc points to that file for trusted certificates.

What's going on here?

Comment: For your key-cert pairs, you need an unbroken chain of certs all the way up to the CA. It's possible the CA you chose is not in your ca-bundle.crt file.

Comment: I made sure to import the root and all intermediate CA certs into ca-bundle.crt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My problem was related to Apple's Keychain Access app.

If a certificate request is created in Safari, the private key is stored in the OS X login keychain. The public key can be downloaded subsequently using Safari as a file named `pki`, which can be imported to the login keychain using Keychain Access. When exporting the certificate, the certficate chain (CA, intermediate CA, root CA) is **not** included in the PKCS#12 file (which causes the error message). Of course, you could manually export all the elements of your certificate chain and merge them using e.g. OpenSSL.

But it is **much** easier to create certificate requests in Firefox and export ("backup") the complete certificate from this browser. A PKCS#12 file from Firefox can be imported using `smime_keys` without further ado.

Summary: I created `~/.smime` and copied some trusted CA certs to this directory (`~/.smime/ca-bundle.crt`). To import my personal certificate, I executed `smime_keys add_p12 cert.p12`, then added the following lines

```
set smime_is_default
set smime_default_key="foobar"
```

to my `~/.muttrc`, where "foobar" is the key ID returned for my personal cert by `smime_keys list`.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could add details on how you achieved this.

Comment: Sure, I updated the answer with configuration details.